# Если задать QMap через new, а в него положить ссылки на uchar* массивы созданные также через new, что будет при вызове delete QMap?

Tags: c++, qt

Удалятся ли все uchar* массивы?

Comment: Естественно uchar массивы нужно удалить, перед удалением qmap. Иначе получите утечку памяти. Раз есть **new**, значит должен быть и **delete**.

Comment: хотя что такое "ссылки на uchar* массивы" ?

Comment: судя по описанию — нет, но без кода понять, что именно подразумевается в вопросе доподлинно невозможно...

Comment: А чем обусловлено использование new/delete? Можно же QMap<Key, QByteArray>, и всё будет хорошо

Comment: QByteArray не нравится не освоился с ним еще, ну и там тоже будет нью делит

Comment: @DowJhob почему там будет new/delete ?

Comment: потому что читается хмл из файла и преобразовывается в бин, таких кусков много, их надо где то хранить